# I have trouble with MarkerClusterer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

Can someone explain to me why MarkerClusterer shows 2 markers when there is only one marker!
this is my code:

```
   const MapWithMarkerClusterer = compose(
   withProps({
    googleMapURL:
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=API_KEY&v=3.exp& 
    libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    center: { lat: 25.03, lng: 121.6 },
   }),
   withScriptjs,
   withGoogleMap
   )((props) => (
   <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={10}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 19.807151, lng: 105.795327 }}
   >
    <MarkerClusterer averageCenter enableRetinaIcons gridSize={100}>
      <Marker
        position={{
          lat: 19.807151,
          lng: 105.795327,
        }}
      />
    </MarkerClusterer>
    </GoogleMap>
   ));

   export default MapWithMarkerClusterer;
```

photo description

Comment: There is no photo dear Conqueror135.

Comment: I removed the API key in your question. Please don't share your API key in public sites in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! because strictMode!Everything was fine when I deleted it!